# Having trouble with onclick displaying and hiding differnt text

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table where the text in column on the left can be clicked and the text in the column on the right will change accordingly. The way it should work is when one of the options on the left is clicked, only the text on the right that corresponds to the selected option appears. However, when I click one of my options on the left it just hides all of the text on the right and does not display the part I want to see.

```js
 var selectColor = function( element ) {

                /* Change color of text based on current selection */
                prots = document.getElementsByClassName( "prot_id" );
                for ( i = 0; i < prots.length; ++i ) {
                    prots.item(i).style.color = 'black';
                    element.style.color = 'red';
                }            
            }

            var selectProtein = function( element ) {
                /* Change what info is displayed based on current selection */
                var proteinInfo = document.getElementsByClassName( "prot_func" ) ;

                for( j = 0; j < proteinInfo.length; ++j ) {
                    proteinInfo[j].style['display'] = 'none' ;
                }
                
                var proteinIDs = ["gria1", "gria2", "gria3", "gria4"] ;

                proteinIDs.forEach(function(entry) {
                    if( element.src.includes(entry)) {
                    var theProtein = document.getElementById(entry) ;
                    theProtein.style['display'] = 'block' ;
                    }
                })
            }
```

```html
<head>
     <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='./index.css'> 
</head>

    <body>
        
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <p class="prot_id" onclick="selectColor(this); selectProtein(this)">GRIA1_HUMAN</p>
                    <p class="prot_id" onclick="selectColor(this); selectProtein(this)">GRIA2_HUMAN</p>
                    <p class="prot_id" onclick="selectColor(this); selectProtein(this)">GRIA3_HUMAN</p>
                    <p class="prot_id" onclick="selectColor(this); selectProtein(this)">GRIA4_HUMAN</p>
                </td>
                <td> 
                   <p id="gria1" class="prot_func">...</p>

                   <p id="gria2" class="prot_func">...</p>

                   <p id="gria3" class="prot_func">...</p>

                   <p id="gria4" class="prot_func">...</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </body>
```

Comment: Can you post a more complete code snippet - e.g. including the html table definition.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues that you are having so I updated your code.

I got rid of onclick and went with an event handler instead.

I got rid of the protein array loop and just added each id as a data attribute to the paragraph tags.

Instead of hiding/showing based on the style, I just add/remove a class instead.

```js
var selectColor = function(element) {

  /* Change color of text based on current selection */
  prots = document.getElementsByClassName("prot_id");
  for (i = 0; i < prots.length; ++i) {
    prots.item(i).classList.remove("active");
  }

  element.classList.add("active")
}

var selectProtein = function(element) {
  var proteinInfo = document.getElementsByClassName("prot_func");

  for (j = 0; j < proteinInfo.length; ++j) {
    proteinInfo[j].classList.remove("active");
  }

  theProtein = document.querySelector("#" + element.dataset.id);
  theProtein.classList.add("active");
}

document.querySelectorAll(".prot_id").forEach(function(el) {
  el.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    selectColor(e.target);
    selectProtein(e.target)
  });
});
```

```css
.prot_func {
  display: none;
}

.prot_func.active {
  display: block;
}

.prot_id.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p class="prot_id" data-id="gria1">GRIA1_HUMAN</p>
      <p class="prot_id" data-id="gria2">GRIA2_HUMAN</p>
      <p class="prot_id" data-id="gria3">GRIA3_HUMAN</p>
      <p class="prot_id" data-id="gria4">GRIA4_HUMAN</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p id="gria1" class="prot_func">.1..</p>

      <p id="gria2" class="prot_func">.2..</p>

      <p id="gria3" class="prot_func">.3..</p>

      <p id="gria4" class="prot_func">..4.</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

From your snippet, you are going to show the options on the right side based on the selected `p` tag content.

So if `GRIA1_HUMAN` is selected, `gria1` should be shown.

You can get the value of `p` content using `innerText` attribute and compare the values using it. I have attached the working example.

```js
var selectColor = function (element) {
  /* Change color of text based on current selection */
  prots = document.getElementsByClassName("prot_id");
  for ( i = 0; i < prots.length; ++i ) {
    prots.item(i).style.color = 'black';
  }
  
  element.style.color = 'red';
}

var selectProtein = function (element) {
  /* Change what info is displayed based on current selection */
  var proteinInfo = document.getElementsByClassName("prot_func") ;

  for( j = 0; j < proteinInfo.length; ++j) {
    proteinInfo[j].style['display'] = 'none' ;
  }
  
  var proteinIDs = ["gria1", "gria2", "gria3", "gria4"] ;

  const elementText = element.innerText.toLowerCase();
  proteinIDs.forEach(function(entry) {
    if(elementText.includes(entry)) {
      var theProtein = document.getElementById(entry);
      theProtein.style['display'] = 'block';
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p class="prot_id" onclick="selectColor(this); selectProtein(this)">GRIA1_HUMAN</p>
    </td>
    <td> 
      <p id="gria1" class="prot_func">...</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><p class="prot_id" onclick="selectColor(this); selectProtein(this)">GRIA2_HUMAN</p></td>
    <td><p id="gria2" class="prot_func">...</p></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><p class="prot_id" onclick="selectColor(this); selectProtein(this)">GRIA3_HUMAN</p></td>
    <td><p id="gria3" class="prot_func">...</p></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><p class="prot_id" onclick="selectColor(this); selectProtein(this)">GRIA4_HUMAN</p></td>
    <td><p id="gria4" class="prot_func">...</p></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```